# TextToSpeech stop() не работает

Tags: java, android, text-to-speech

Я пытаюсь остановить TextToSpeech по нажатию на кнопку назад. Но речь не прерывается, даже если я закрою приложение (только когда очищу кэш — Синтезатор речи Google). Как мне решить эту проблему, помогите разобраться.

```
private boolean mShouldSpeak = true;
TextToSpeech tts;
 @Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_cat);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, new TextToSpeech.OnInitListener() {
        @Override
        public void onInit(int status) {
            if (status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS) {
                tts.setEngineByPackageName(enginePackageName);
                tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());
                tts.setPitch(0);
                tts.setSpeechRate(1);
               speak();
            }
        }
    });
}
 private void speak() {

    if (mShouldSpeak == true)
    {
        tts.speak("Автор: " +getResources().getString(R.string.catAuthor), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(getResources().getString(R.string.catName), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.speak(getResources().getString(R.string.catDesc), TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
        tts.playSilence(1000, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_ADD, null);
    }

}
 @Override
protected void onDestroy() {
    if (tts != null)
    {
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
public void onBackPressed() {

    onDestroy();
    super.onBackPressed();

}
```

Comment: Метод onDestroy не всегда вызывается, и Вы не можете знать наверняка, вызовет ли его ОС или нет. Поэтому лучше вызывать tts.shutdown(); в onStop

Comment: @Ksenia гарантированно системой вызывается onPause, остальные методы, следующие за ним, включая onStop, могут не вызываться в определенных условиях.

Comment: Добрый вечер. Ни один из этих методов не работает. При отладке код в них выполняется, причем stop() возвращается с кодом 0 (SUCCESS).

Comment: Может попробовать по нажатию на кнопку добавлять в очередь tts пустую строку и использовать QUEUE_FLUSH. Правда смотрится как костыль, но может получится.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Проблема оказалась в движке TTS:

```
tts.setEngineByPackageName(enginePackageName)
```

эта функция содержит допустимое имя пакета модуля преобразования текста в речь, установленного на устройстве, например `com.google.android.tts` или  `com.svox.pico`.

Если этот параметр не будет применен, движок, выбранный в качестве устройства по умолчанию в тексте, будет привязан к настройкам речи.

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте завершить в onStop()

```
@Override
protected void onStop()
{
    super.onStop();

    if(tts != null){
        tts.shutdown();
    }       
}
```

так же в onBackPressed()

```
@Override
public void onBackPressed(){

        super.onBackPressed();

        if(tts != null){
            tts.shutdown();
        }       
}
```

п.с. принудительный вызов onDestroy в onBackPressed лучше удалить.

Comment: Добрый вечер) Без изменений. На англоязычном форме предположили, что я останавливаю не тот tts. Но он вроде как один здесь, не понимаю, в чём косяк.